# Rearrangement problem of the letters of a given word

Tags: probability

In how many ways can we rearrange the letters in the word INDIVISIBILITY such that no two 'I's are adjacent to each other?

My try : Total number of rearrangement is  ${14 \choose 6} ×8! $.I'm trying to count the complement event of the required event ,then I will reduce this count from the total number of rearrangement. The complement event is the union of  $5$ disjoint events ; two 'I's are adjacent, three 'I's are adjacent, 
four 'I's are adjacent, five 'I's are adjacent, six 'I's are adjacent. The counting of such events are ${13\choose 5}×8!,{12\choose 4}×8! , {11\choose 3} ×8! , {10\choose 2}×8! ,{9\choose 1}×8! $ respectively.  I call sum of this numerical $S$. Then I get my required counting ${14\choose 8}×8! - S$.

But the problem is that I'm sure that I have done wrong  (I've the answer key). But how? Where did I misstak? Please give me a hint to solve it. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $6$ I's and $8$ other letters. Start with "_X_X_X_X_X_X_X_X_" where "_" represents an I or nothing and "X" represents one of the other $8$ letters. There are $\binom{9}{6}$ ways to place the I's, and $8!$ ways to arrange the other letters. This give us a total of $\binom{9}{6}\times8!=3386880$ ways to arrange the letters.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the problem with this approach, consider the following rearrangement:
$$\text{IINDVIISIIBLTY}$$
You listed five possible events to consider:

> two 'I's are adjacent, three 'I's are adjacent, four 'I's are adjacent, five 'I's are adjacent, six 'I's are adjacent

To which category does the above rearrangement belong?

Your formulation considers "groups of I," which is fundamentally reasonable, but you're missing some of the possibilities of what that might entail, resulting in an undercount. The five combinatorial expressions you listed would correctly answer the following questions:

- $\binom{13}{5} \times 8!$: How many ways are there to insert exactly 5 copies of the letter I into a rearrangement of NDVSBLTY?
- $\binom{12}{4} \times 8!$: How many ways are there to insert exactly 4 copies of the letter I into a rearrangement of NDVSBLTY?
- $\binom{11}{3} \times 8!$: How many ways are there to insert exactly 3 copies of the letter I into a rearrangement of NDVSBLTY?
- $\binom{10}{2} \times 8!$: How many ways are there to insert exactly 2 copies of the letter I into a rearrangement of NDVSBLTY?
- $\binom{9}{1} \times 8!$: How many ways are there to insert exactly 1 copy of the letter I into a rearrangement of NDVSBLTY?

However, having two adjacent I's (which you could imagine as 5 "blocks of I") is not the same thing as inserting 5 I's. Your combinatorial expression won't be able to tell **II**NDVISILIBITY apart from INDV**II**SIBILITY, for instance; it would just see them both as being _NDV_S_B_L_TY, where the blanks are filled somehow with I's.

**Suggestion for how to answer the question:** I think counting the complement is much harder in this case than just counting the object directly. Other than potentially an I at the very end, each I must be followed by *something other than I*. So, break this into two cases. In the first case, the rearrangements do not end in I, and in the second case they do. For the first case, you have six "IX" blocks, where the X must be filled with a consonant, and you have two leftover consonants that you can distribute anywhere. Consider how many ways you can place these six IX blocks along with the two extra consonants, then consider how many ways there are to actually order the consonants. You can do something similar for the case where the rearrangements end in I.

**EDIT:** I think Daniel Mathias has provided a cleaner and more clear hint than I did for how to correctly solve the problem.

Comment: thanks to explain me explicitly. can you give me more poblems (books , links,notes etc) like it ?

Comment: I wish I could do that, but unfortunately I don't know of any good resources for things like this. As far as I can tell, everyone learns combinatorics by basically doing what you're doing: taking some ordinary textbook, doing problems, trying new strategies, making mistakes, and identifying why those mistakes are wrong.